# JSON body gets corrupted when sending to Web API endpoint on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I am sending a huge number (30 000 calls one by one) of JSONs over HTTP to Web API endpoint hosted on Azure. While most of them are processed just fine, about 1%-2% of JSONs received by WebAPI is simply corrupted and cannot be deserialized.

The code that sends messages looks following:

```
private async Task Send(string messageBody)
{
   try
   {
      HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _configurationService.ServiceUrl);
      requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(messageBody, Encoding.UTF8);
      requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
      HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
      ... // do rest of the stuff - check http codes, handle exceptions, etc
    }
```

The messageBody string is a json array of 100 items serialized with Json.net. Sample:

```
[{"ContentSnippet":"Body142370","ContentImageUrl":null,"ContentNotFullySupported":false,"Title":"142370","ContentType":9,"ContentId":"98fdb109-6548-40b9-900b-6914f16a6481","ActionType":14,"ActionDate":"2016-08-31T07:42:45.3161067Z","ActionByUserFirstName":"W","ActionByUserLastName":"J","ActionByUserId":"92caa514-7168-4085-bc17-85ef2fd2a682","UserId":"96e243eb-97be-4d36-9881-74e761def5aa","CommunityId":"10d44cf3-44ea-451e-8bfb-5275ba2f28a5","NotificationType":0}, {...next item in array...}]
```

The backend code I am using for diagnosing it looks following:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/feed")]
public HttpResponseMessage Insert(IEnumerable<FeedItem> feedItems)
{
   Stream s = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
   s.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s))
   {
      string reqestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
```

What I get on backend side (in requestBody variable) is:

```
[""ContentSnippet"":""Body142370"",""ContentImageUrl"":null,""ContentNotFullySupported"":false,""Title"":""142370"",""ContentType"":9,""ContentId"":""98fdb109-6548-40b9-900b-6914f16a6481"",""ActionType"":14,""ActionDate"":""2016-08-31T07:42:45.e����3��   v��tionByUse��E<stName""��K��UCctionByUserLast��0���d�v���r�P�gByUserId"":""92UŇ���U�sH/ia�y��""L)?8:�ԙN�JY�:,���X�1;�%�x!;   `��,�981-74
```

Interestingly - it happens only for 1% - 2% of calls. More interestingly - when I try to simply resend the same JSON, everything works fine. So its a phantom issue (i dont see any patterns indicating when) - but still it happens.

I tried changing HttpClient to RestSharp but the result were event worse.

What is going on here?

Comment: You got any solution ? I have also faced same issue which arises rarely.